# PCI compliance - storing billing data

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, pci-compliance

I am developing a shopping cart and if possible, would like to store:

Name
Billing Address
Zip Code

Into a MySQL database.  This would be nice because returning customers wouldn't have to re-enter billing information each time they check out.  I am not going to store any credit card data.

Would I be in violation of PCI standards by doing this?

Comment: Given how serious PCI compliance is, do you really want to take some Joe Random Person's answer as gospel? Go read the standards yourself: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PCI Compliance does not cover the storing of a customers Name, Address etc. It deals with the handling of credit card data. From a PCI compliance perspective as long as you store no more than the last 4 numbers of the credit card in plain text you should fine to store the customers billing information for use on a future visit.

Of course it has never hurt to be super security conscience and to store all customer information encrypted, but as long as you are noting storing credit cards you should be fine to store customer name, address etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can encrypt and store them. Then you have to decrypt it before using. You can't show it decrypted anywhere.

Comment: You can't even keep it decrypted in Database too. Basically you can't store plain card number anywhere.

Comment: I'm not looking to store any credit card numbers, expiration date, nothing like that...  Just the address information.

Comment: I think there will be no problem in storing address.